# Any way to make the border nearer to the body content ? (HTML/CSS) Pictures provided

Tags: html, css

What I have done so far : http://goo.gl/sDhLA

What I am supposed to achieve : http://goo.gl/tqo7m

Thanks in advance for any help, newbie in html/css here.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

My bad. I forgotten to mention that I am actually aiming for the results with the least amount of major edits to the code, as there are some code which I can't change. ( stipulated in my assignment ) .

On the other hand, there isn't any harm in learning more stuff though. Learnt more about new commands like line-height,  box-sizing: border-box is really interesting.

However, I was quite sad that negative padding doesn't occur. It would have solved the gap at the left and right edges eh ? :O

Comment: Could you bung the code into something like jsfiddle, would make it easier to edit and and understand what you have so far.

Comment: It's very difficult to comment on that without being able to see the code. There could be a whole bunch of reasons why the border is so far out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: I am not too sure how to go about using jsfiddle, but here is the link =) .  http://jsfiddle.net/LGFLB/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reduce the width for your container (or increase the width of your content).

You should post your code here though, only then I will be able to be sure this answer is correct.

Your code is a mess. Here's what I made (I have the units in `cm` because it will gives better control when printing, you may change the units)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Revisions Bookstore and Cafe</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        @font-face {
            font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
            src:         url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
            src:         local('?'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfontb5K2fJwj') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style:  normal;
        }
        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            border:           0.1cm solid rgb(65, 105, 225);
            font-family:      ChunkFiveRegular,serif;
            background-color: rgb(189, 204, 212);
            font-size:        2em;
        }

        #card div {
            font-family:      ChunkFiveRegular,serif;
        }

        #card {
            font-family:  Verdana,serif;
            width: 15cm;
            padding: 0.2cm;
            border: 0.07cm black solid;
            margin: 1cm auto;
        }

        #card div p {
            padding: 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.2cm 0.4cm;
        }

        #card > p {
            background: black;
            color: white;
            text-align: right;
            padding: 0.1cm;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="card">
    <h1>Revisions Bookstore and Cafe</h1>

    <div>
        <p class="maintext">Custom brewed coffee and hand-selected books.</p>

        <p class="maintext">Special orders are our specialty.</p>
    </div>

    <p>412 N. 25th St.<br/>Richmond, VA 23223<br/>(804) 555-2565</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>

​
```

Comment: Not sure if I can use pastebay, but it looks clearer compared to jsfiddle ? http://www.pastebay.net/717519

Comment: Are you trying to produce a printable card? Any reason you're not using `cm` as your value but `em`?

Comment: No, this is actually for an assignment =) 
Oh I thought the trend nowadays is to use em .. guess I was wrong in that aspect haha.

Comment: @TheKraven: There are 3 types of units, absolute units (px, cm), **elastic** units, (em, rem) and **fluid** units (%). Setting the widths of elements as `em` is great for websites where they allow they user to change the font-size (or in website where ie6/7 support is mandatory). Usually, you'd want to use PX for better display on screen, or fluid if you wish to address a wider range of screen sizes (although there're @media queries for that today)

Comment: What does the * refer to ? Under  * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }.
And why do you separate the declaration into #card div,#card,#card div p and #card > p ?
Can't all of them be declared under #card ? Gotta need work more on my coding lol.

Comment: * in css simply means that those styles are applied to all elements.

Comment: no worries c:, it helps alot with normalizing css and be super useful when dealing with many elements that all have common css. Also keep in mind that you can use it anywhere within any kind of rule in your css. i.e `#ul li * { *rules* }`

Comment: Am i right to assume that the margins declared under * overides all other margin declarations ?

Comment: @TheKraven: `#card div p` literally means "p element inside of div element inside of  element with ID of 'card'". CSS does not support nested declarations. (Though there are CSS frameworks which does, see LESS).

Comment: I see.. thanks =D . Btw, I can't figure out #card > p . Mind explaining it to me ? =)

Comment: @TheKraven: Sure, the `>` operator in CSS means the **direct child operator**, meaning it would only match the `p` element which is directly under `#card`, so that the 2 description lines will not be affected (because they are inside of another nested div).

Comment: Also, if this answer is correct, please consider accepting it by pressing the large (hollow) green tick under the score value.

Answer (score 0):

Well I looked at achieving the result you are wanting so i've basically manually set things to the same width as your original but with a couple of modifications (mainly just setting margins and widths) while keeping things in em format.

but heres the new css:

```
  @font-face {
            font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
            src: url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
            src: local('?'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.woff')format('woff'),url('Chunkfivewebfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfontb5K2fJwj')format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            }

  h1 {
    text-align: center;

    border: 0.1em solid rgb(65,105,225);
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
    padding: 0.25em;

    font-family: ChunkFiveRegular;
    background-color: rgb(189,204,212);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2em;
    }

  #contact {
    text-align: right;

    margin: 0 8px 8px;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: ChunkFiveRegular;
    color: white;
    background-color: #212100;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

  #box {

    margin: 0 8px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    }

  .maintext {
    text-align: left;
    }

  #body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 0.07cm solid black;
  margin: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 23em;
  margin-right: 4em;
  width: 33.4em;

  }

</style>
```

Comment: Hi, the border seem to have disappeared =X . Or I copied the code wrongly somewhere..

Comment: haha the border is definitely still there, maybe due to bram's tip above you removed the id #body from the body tag in which case simply taking away the '#' in my css should fix it. c:

Comment: Oh you are spot on =P . On a sidenote, under #contact, there's margin: 0 8px; and margin-bottom: 8px; . I assumed that margin-bottom would be redudant, but it isn't. Why is this the case ? I thought the 1st margin declaration with 0 8px covers the bottom margin with 8px ?

Comment: I just found your question again, and yes you are right it is redundant however the new margin css would be `margin: 0 8px 8px;` to compensate for the removal of `margin-bottom: 8px;`

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/LGFLB/1/

A hint: do NOT use an ID 'body' (or any html tag as ID for that matter)! It gets confusing! You can easily target the body by simply using `body`.

I have kept the HTML structure you proposed. I changed quite a lot of the CSS. Especially the width, margins and size. Also note `box-sizing`!

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 0.07cm solid black;
  margin: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 17em;
  margin-right: 4em;
  width: 45em;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0.1em solid rgb(65,105,225);
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0.2em auto;
  padding: 0.25em;
  font-family: Rockwell;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(189,204,212);
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 2.5em;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contact {
  text-align: right;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  padding: 0.25em;
  font-family: Rockwell;
  color: white;
  background-color: #212100;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#box {
  width: 92%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 2;
}

.maintext {
  text-align: left;
}
```

​

Comment: Please copy the relevant parts of your code into your answer.